# Accessing specific array indices using the go template library

Tags: templates, go

Say i have a data structure like this:

```
type Foo struct {
  Bar []struct {
    FooBar string
  }
}
```

And i fill it such that Bar has 3 elements. Now, using the `template` library, how can i access say the 3rd element's `FooBar` in that slice? I have tried the following with no success:

```
{Foo.Bar[2].FooBar}
{Foo.Bar.2.FooBar}
```

Now, i know that i can use `{.repeated section Foo.Bar} {FooBar} {.end}`, but that gives me the value of foobar for *each* element, rather than just a specific one. I have googled and asked on irc to no avail...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain this just isn't possible. Perhaps there's a way you could restructure your data so that it's all named fields.

Or just write some more logic in your actual application. Array indexing is somewhat beyond the scope of the template package I would think.

Comment: That is what i did, but it was a lot more work than just using the indexes in the template file. Ah well...

Answer (score 3):

Using the new `text/template` or `html/template`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "text/template" // or html/template
    "os"
)

func main() {
    tmpl, err := template.New("name").Parse("{{index . 0}}")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, []string{"yup, that's me", "not that!"})
}
```

Comment: Note that I asked this question before the new template library existed, so this wasn't possible then. Nevertheless, it's good to add now for the reference of people from the future.

Comment: @crazy2be I knew that, and I agree.